# was knocked his tooth out or was knocked his tooth out of

Tags: passive-voice

> She knocked out his tooth.

If I change this sentence into passive,

> 1.He was knocked his tooth out.
>
> 2.He was knocked his tooth out of.

Which is suitable and grammatical?

Comment: "His tooth was knocked out (by her)."?

Answer (score 1):

The subject of a passive sentence must be an object of the verb or an 'oblique'—object of a preposition phrase—affected by the verb in the active version. In your base active sentence the only entity which qualifies is *his tooth*:

> His tooth was knocked out (by her).

Because *HE* is neither an object nor an oblique but a possessive it can't be cast as a passive subject.

To cast *HE* as subject in this sort of context we don't use the passive but an 'experiential' *HAVE* or *GET*:

> He had/got his tooth knocked out (by her).

This is not a passive but it has much the same effect.